# Magento 2.3: Get list of unused product attributes

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I want to get a list of all unused product attributes through database or code. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> SELECT attribute_id, attribute_code, frontend_label FROM eav_attribute
> WHERE entity_type_id = 4 AND attribute_id NOT IN(SELECT attribute_id
> FROM eav_entity_attribute);

You can change entity_type_id for whatever entity you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This query gets all the unassigned attributes. I want to get a list of 'unused' attributes(Attributes which may be assigned to the attribute set but never used in any products).

Comment: You can change the table name in inner query like "catalog_product_entity_int" I think it should work.